# What DOM elements are not HTML elements?

Tags: html, dom

The [MDN documentation on addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) reads:

> It works on any DOM element, not just HTML elements.

What DOM elements are not HTML elements? XML? Others?

Comment: DOM is not HTML. DOM is an API for JavaScript, HTML is a markup language. The above posted statement means that it works both on DOM and HTML elements. There is nothing implied that they could by any means be the same thing.

Comment: text nodes, comment, etc?

Comment: A little correction to my above comment: DOM is an API specification and it is not specifically only for JavaScipt, though it is mostly used this way.

Comment: The HTML spec describes HTML in terms of a text document with a specific syntax. The DOM on the other hand describes the object-model that the browser generates, when it parses the HTML document. See at [here](https://css-tricks.com/dom/) you will get clarity

Comment: Text nodes, SVG elements

Answer (score 2):

You can add event listeners to any DOM object not only HTML elements. i.e the window object. Basically, all the statement is saying is that you are not confined to the HTML elements only.

> The DOM is a W3C (World Wide Web Consortium) standard.
>
> The DOM defines a standard for accessing documents:
>
> "The W3C Document Object Model (DOM) is a platform and language-neutral interface that allows programs and scripts to dynamically access and update the content, structure, and style of a document."
>
> The W3C DOM standard is separated into 3 different parts:
>
> - Core DOM - standard model for all document types
> - XML DOM - standard model for XML documents
> - HTML DOM - standard model for HTML documents

Here is a useful link which should give you more information about the HTML DOM http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp.

You should also have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp.

Here is the official W3C recommendation: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/introduction.html